# Updated automatically every 5 minutes - Doesn't really update sheet data when published to web

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So i have this google sheet which updates values in the cells every 5 minutes. While this works perfectly fine on the sheet. But the issue is when i published to web, It does'nt update anymore until manually refreshed, Even though the bottom of the page says –Updated automatically every 5 minutes. I have checked the calculation settings, Nothing so far, Is there a workaround for this?

I tried changing the calculation settings in the spreadsheet settings but it did not work.